# Can't convert Apigee Java Object response to string

Tags: java, apigee

I'm using the GetAPIProduct policy (see http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/retrieve-api-product-settings-using-getapiproduct
) to get a list of scopes.  Then in a JavaScript callout, I try to reference that list of scopes, but instead of text I get back something like this (the hex chunk at the end changes with each call):

```
 [Ljava.lang.String;@19baa7ed
```

There doesn't seem to be anything I can do to turn it into an array I can access using Javascript.  I'm in a Free org so Java is not an option.  I've tried String(), myvar.toString() and even the Rhino context.javaToJs which doesn't seem to exist in Apigee.

Any ideas how I can either convert this to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the value of `getapiproduct.{policyname}.apiproduct.scopes` is a zero-based array of objects. Each of those objects, though, can be converted to a string that is a scope name.

So here's how you access the array of scopes:

```
var scopeArray=context.getVariable("getapiproduct.RetrieveProductInfo.apiproduct.scopes");

// you can use either of these methods to convert the array elements
var firstElement = String(scopeArray[0]);
var secondElement = scopeArray[1]+'';

var scopeArrayLen = scopeArray.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the question, but is some additional information that may be valuable.

The `GetAPIPRoductInfo` gets the list of scopes on a product. Conversely, the `GetOAuthV2Info` policy gets information about an OAUthV2 token. Assuming you have a token you could do something like this:

```
<GetOAuthV2Info name='GetOAuthV2Info-TokenScopes'>
  <!-- use one of the following: a referenced variable or -->
  <!-- an explicitly passed access_token -->
  <AccessToken ref='access_token'/>

  <!--
      On Success, the following flow variables will be set.
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.access_token
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.scope
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.refresh_token
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.accesstoken.{custom_attribute_name}
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.developer.id
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.developer.app.name
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.expires_in
      oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.status
  -->
</GetOAuthV2Info>
```

Then you can use that information in a subsequent JS callout to check the scopes for the token against whatever requirement you have:

```
// checkScope.js
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

var varname = 'oauthv2accesstoken.GetOAuthV2Info-TokenScopes.scope',
    approvedScopes = context.getVariable(varname),
    check = false;

approvedScopes = approvedScopes.split(' ');
// approvedScopes is now a JavaScript array of strings, that lists
// the scopes the user approved for the requesting client (app).
//
// You can now compare that list against the scopes required
// for an operation or resource, and then set a variable 
// determining whether the token is good for the request. 

context.setVariable('scopeCheck.ok', check);
```